# "Click to use Flash" button doesn't always show on Safari

Tags: javascript, flash, safari

I'm working on a site that uses a video recorded via the user's webcam. The recorder library is not my code, but at a high level, it tries to use HTML5 (Media Recorder API) where possible and falls back onto Flash where not. On Safari, this means Flash. Basically, I supply the library with a div where I want the recorder to appear and it inserts it there.

However, some of my users were reporting confusion on Safari (the video recorder was not showing up) and I was able to reproduce this confusing situation. With Safari 12.0 on Mac OS 10.13.6 with Adobe Flash installed and enabled in Safari:

[image]

when I navigate to the page with the video recorder, I expect to see a "Click to use Flash" button on the video recorder area. But, when I first load the page, the area is complete blank. Strangely, it appears that the button is indeed there, but just not showing:

- When I click on the area where the button should be, it responds (and prompts me to enable flash)
- When I open the Web Inspector tool, the button appears (you can also see the code for the Flash object here that gets inserted dynamically)

[image]

- When I simply resize the window, the button appears

[image]

I don't use Safari as my regular browser, so it's not like I have a highly customized configuration. Unless I'm missing something, this feels like a bug in Safari (I filed a bug report, but they specifically say they do not respond).

I've tried some javascript tricks to "re-draw" the element (e.g. hide then show) to try and get the button to show up right away, but without any luck. Obviously I can't tell users "resize the window" or "click in the middle where there is supposed to be a button".

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If so, how? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't exactly recall if I was able to find a solution, but it does seem to happen less often now. Not sure if Safari improved or not. Sorry, nothing concrete to offer.

Comment: Actually, @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass, I just remembered what I did about it. I added this text to that page, only for Desktop Safari users: "If Flash is enabled, you may have to click above for a Click to use Flash button to appear.". Obviously far from ideal.